# Making a control visible on a seperate page, but not visible on the page which contains the control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a masterpage (which we will call 'default'). This contains a second page (web user control) - 'second'. And finally a third 'print' page. The 'print' page is also a web user control, however, it merely has a placeholder that contains the 'second' page.

Is there a way I can add a control to the 'second' page - such as a literal, and only have it visible on the 'print' page?

Comment: Define contains.  Do you mean you have a page Default.aspx which has two controls on it, user control and print control (which is going to be a copy of the user control)?

Comment: The masterpage 'default' contains a 'content' placeholder. There are two web user controls, 'second' and 'print'. Either may be displayed in the 'content' placeholder (based on user navigation). The 'print' user control has a placeholder which contains the 'second' user control. So yes in theory, 'print' is a copy of 'second'. However, I want to add a literal control to 'second' that only displays on 'print'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like CSS will actually be the best approach to your issue. Use the [media attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) to specify what is and what is not visible. Here's an example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" media="screen">
```

which contains...

```
.yourClass
{
    display:none;
}
```

and then also have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print">
```

which contains...

```
.yourClass
{
    display:block;
}
```

So, your page would include both stylesheets, and your control would use the `yourClass` CSS class. The end result would be that whatever elements use `yourClass` would only be visible when printing.

Comment: upvoted, assuming the 'print' control is for printing only.  if not, you might need some code-behind logic.

Comment: This sounds like what I want. 

However, I have question:
When you say, 'would only be visible when printing' - does that mean it won't show up  when the 'print' control is being displayed on screen? But it will be visible once it is printed?

The 'print' control is only used for printing, but it does display to the user as a sort of 'print preview' as well.